# reversing on windows x86_64 with radare2

Tags: disassembly, radare2

I am trying to get radare2 to "run" on my windows7 64-bit system.

I downloaded the radare2-1.5.0.zip file from http://radare.org, but when I unzip it and try to run any of the tools, I simply get
"there is a problem with this program and it must be closed".

Is it possibly because these were compiled for x86 not x64 operating system?

Comment: I have similar issue - try report an issue in their GitHub repo?

Comment: Same occurs for me on Windows 10

Comment: @fpmurphy1 why not run radare2 Linux binary under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL/LXSS), it work without any problem under Windows 10 for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use the binaries built with MSVC http://radare.mikelloc.com/get/2.3.0/radare2_installer-msvc_32-2.3.0.exe or this one http://radare.mikelloc.com/get/2.3.0/radare2_installer-msvc_64-2.3.0.exe

Comment: File not found.

Comment: Updated the links.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://github.com/radare/radare2/releases
2. Click on the link after "Builds:", e.g. http://radare.mikelloc.com/get/2.3.0/
3. Download installer, e.g. radare2_installer-msvc_64-2.3.0.exe
4. Run installer
5. Run path\to\your\home_dir\AppData\Local\Programs\radare2\radare2.exe

Answer (score 0):

The version 1.5.0 built with mingw32 is not working, try to use 1.4.0 instead until 1.6.0 is released [here](https://github.com/radare/radare2/releases) or download the msvc build [here](http://cloud.radare.org/get/1.5.0/radare2-w64_msvc-1.5.0.zip).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was solved using the x64 version. Just download http://radare.mikelloc.com/get/1.5.0/radare2-w64-1.5.0.zip and give it a try.